# SQL insert command in relation table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Sorry I am newbie in SQL and I need help with a sql relation table.

I need to insert query to my relation table.

In my program, I have a book and this book has many categories.

Should I create a one to many, or many to many relations for that?

And how can I make insert command for adding a book to my table.
I tried to do somethings but i dont know its correct or not.

> tblBook: BookID, BookName , CategoryID
>       tblCat : CatID, CatName,

I create foreign key

`tblCat.CatID -> tblBook.CatID` like as that. Do I need third table? Or is that enough?

Then I didn't understand how I will insert many category to book table?

Could you help me? thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a relation many to many, because one book can have different categories and one is for different book.

You need 3 tables:

> tblBook: BookID, BookName
>
> tblCat : CatID, CatName
>
> tblRelationBookCat : BookID, CatID

To insert, you have to:

Add a book in your tblBook

```
INSERT INTO tblBook(BookID, BookName) VALUES(1, 'Star-Wars');
```

Add a category in your tblCat

```
INSERT INTO tblCat(CatID, CatName) VALUES(1, 'Sci-Fi');
```

Add the relation in your tblRelationBookCat

```
INSERT INTO tblRelationBookCat(BookID, CatID) VALUES(1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you did a relation with two tables. You also should make one-to-many relation. That's OK and there is no need to create third table.  In insertion, you need rows on category table. Because, when you adding a row with value of foreign key on book table logically you have to add a exists category id on category table's primary key.

Example :

```
tblCat            |  tblBook
--------------    |  ---------
CatID  CatName    |   BookID      BookName       CategoryID
1      Sci-Fi     |     1         Star-Wars          1
2      Adventure  |     2         Witcher            2
                  |     3         Romeo & Juliet     3 (???)
```

SQL Query :

```
INSERT INTO tblBook(BookName, CategoryID) VALUES('Star-Wars',1);
```

Comment: Thank you. But if my book has more than one category, while i run this query it will add only one category for a book.How can i add more category for a book in an insert query.

Comment: That situation, you may need fourth or fifth tables or you can just add more categoryID columns on book table. Which means foreign keys more than one. Ex. CategoryID, CategoryID_2, CategoryID_3...
My opinion is adding more foreign key..